# How do I check for potential merge/rebase conflicts in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a simple way to check if a merge/rebase will yield file conflicts, without actually performing the merge/rebase?

I want to be able to decide whether to:

- rebase if the touched file set (mine vs. theirs) are different
- merge if we've been messing with the same files.

Since a bad merge (caused by resolving conflicts the wrong way by human error) is easier to detect and reverse if I do a merge of two heads, rather than having done rebase. Especially if I push my changes and than later realized that something was messed up.

(It's not possible to always check everything beforehand, as we don't have a totally comprehensive test-suite.).

And.. I'm running Windows. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, with some aid from Martin's answer, I've come up with the rebaseif extension, which does what I want.

Essentially, it tries to rebase using the internal merge tool, if that fails (which it does for any conflict), it aborts and does a merge with the user's preferred tool.

See https://bitbucket.org/marcusl/ml-hgext/src/tip/rebaseif.py for details.

**Update**

In recent months, I've gone back to just do a merge, since it's inherently safe. A non-conflict rebase might still muck things up since dependent files can affect the change. (i.e. a rebase loses information of how the code looked before merge).

As the rebaseif author, I recommend to use plain old merge instead. :)

Comment: ... That the author doesn't trust. :-) +1 to Macke for saying so.  -1 to people who have more trust in something than its author does.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to use `hg merge` if the changes overlap and `hg rebase` otherwise since `hg rebase` make a merge internally and will let you resolve it using the same tools as `hg merge`.

As for testing if a merge or rebase will cause conflicts, then you can use

```
$ hg merge --tool internal:merge
```

in Mercurial 1.7 to override your normal [merge tool configuration](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration). (The `--tool internal:merge` part is new, use `--config ui.merge=internal:merge` in earlier versions of Mercurial.)

Following the merge,

```
$ hg resolve --list
```

will tell you the results and you will get back to where you started with

```
$ hg update --clean .
```

Comment: My reason to choose is that a bad merge (caused by resolving conflicts the wrong way by human error) is easier to detect and reverse if I do a merge of two heads, rather than having done rebase. Especially if I push my changes and than later realized that something was messed up. (It's not possible to always check everything beforehand, as we don't have a totally comprehensive test-suite.). Do you think my use case make sense in that context?

Comment: Marcus: I think that is an interesting and valid reason to prefer merges. I had never thought of the difference in that way before.

Answer (score 3):

You can see if two changesets, REV1 and REV2, affect any of the same files doing something like:

```
(hg status --change REV1 --no-status ; hg status --change REV2 --no-status) | sort | uniq --repeated
```

If that has any output then the same file is touched in both revisions.

That could easily be made a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
(hg status --change $1 --no-status ; hg status --change $2 --no-status) | sort | uniq --repeated
```

which could be run as any of these:

```
./find_overlaps c8f7e56536ab d9e2268e20b9
./find_overlaps 1 33
```

If you really wanted to get fancy you could tweak the script to automatically run merge or rebase depending on whether or not any lines were found.

If you're on windows my god help you. :)

Comment: I have python on windows, so I can easily write a script that does just that. Would've been nice as a plugin though. :)

Comment: This doesn't seem do exactly what I want. I need to check a whole set of revisions, to determine if two anonymous branches contains conflicts, all the way to their common ancestor, not just check two revisions.

Comment: You could install  Cygwin on Windows. :-)  Shades of GIT, eh ?