# How can I tell when a Mercurial merge was trivial?

Tags: mercurial

Sometimes when I do `hg merge` and then check out `hg status`, nothing is printed. Other times I see the actual changes from the other branch. Why is that happening? Can you explain the differences between the merges?

The point of this question is this: we're hooking up Mercurial to Jira and enforce that each commit must contain a task id, and that each such commit will be code reviewed before it's pushed. However, we don't require reviews for "trivial" merges, so we do this check in our commit hook:

```
if not ctx.files():
    return ALLOW_COMMIT
```

However, I've come across situations where the commit was trivial (i.e., Mercurial did all the work and I didn't need to resolve any conflicts) but the `ctx.files()` list is not empty. Most times, however, it works fine. I would have liked to post an example for each case, but I just can't seem to get what the difference is between the two situations.

Basically I'm asking: how can I tell when a Mercurial merge was trivial?

Answer (score 1):

This actually turns out to be a more difficult problem than you'd expect. A year or two ago I tried to write a plugin to generate a "merge diff", showing only the changes introduced in the merge: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergediffExtension

It does have a few bugs… But if it shows an empty merge diff, it definitely means the merge was "trivial" (although there are some trivial merges for which it will show a diff).

Alternatively, this question/answer might help: [How do I check for potential merge/rebase conflicts in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086724/how-do-i-check-for-potential-merge-rebase-conflicts-in-mercurial)

Answer (score 1):

You could replay the merge. If it fails, it is not a trivial one.
If it succeeds, compare the result with the previously commited merge. If both merge results are identical, it was a trivial one, otherwise there have been manual adjustments.

However, this assumes that the replay uses the same merge algorithm as the original merge. Different Mercurial versions and configurations might conflict with this assumption.

#### UPDATE

In case you want to do these checks before commiting a merge, you could use a *pre-merge* hook which "previews" the merge (instead of replaying afterwards). In the hook, do the proposed merge automatically and check for conflicts. No conflicts → potentially trivial, save the merge diff in a temprorary file. Do not forget to abondon the working copy changes caused by your automatic merge (`hg up -r . -C`). Then, when the human wants to commit her actual merge, use a pre-commit hook to check if the manual merge differs from the automatic one stored in the temporary file.  If it differs, a review is required.

However, while this should work in principal, IMHO it is kind of over-engineering.

Comment: How technically do you "replay" a merge?

Comment: @AmirRachum: Replay a merge: get the parent nodes of a merge node, then update to the first parent and issue a `hg merge -r <second-parent>`.

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to do a merge while in a commit hook?

Comment: In fact this is not an option for a commit hook. A pre-push hook might be a better option. Isn't that what you actually want to do -- do some checks before pushing?

Comment: I can do it in the hook push, but I rather do it when there's still a change to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that happening? Can you explain the differences between the merges?

- If it was manual merge, merger can prefer only own changes and discard changes from merged branch, i.e have dummy merge (it can be also non-interactive merge with `tool=internal:local`)
- Rare case - in both files changes (from common parent) may be identical, merge-target will not be changed in this case

**PS**: I don't know, what is `ctx.files()` in hook, but if it's "files, changed in changeset", disabling commit in case of existing such files is Bad Idea (tm) - files may be modified due to clean (no conflicts) merge and in this situation [Martin's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4096340/960558) of replying merge and checking resolve-list seems as rather good approach