# Check if a url is a mercurial repository (like git ls-remote)

Tags: mercurial

How can I check whether a URL points to a mercurial repository? With git, I would use `git ls-remote $url` and check the return value. Is there something similar for hg?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `hg identify` for this: it can be run against a remote repository and Mercurial will abort with an exit code of 255 if the path given isn't a repository. This repository exists:

```
$ hg identify https://bitbucket.org/mg/mercurial-talk; echo $?
7788b512c5bd
0
```

This one doesn't:

```
$ hg identify https://bitbucket.org/mg/git-talk; echo $?
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
255
```

You'll probably want to redirect both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Martin, can I ask you add at least some of your answers as additional topic in Mercurial Tips&Tricks (or - create own hint-list)? Namely: this, merging .hgtags with own mergetool, testing if merge was trivial using "internal:fail"

Comment: Excellent. This exactly answers my question.

Comment: @LazyBadger, are you talking about the [wiki page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks)? It would be cool to link the answers there, but I sad to say that I don't spend much time updating the wiki these days. Please add links as you see fit, though!

Comment: Yes, this wiki page (or in Aragost's Mercurial Kickstart, if you prfer this way). Answers (except from here): [How do I check for potential merge/rebase conflicts in Mercurial?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4096340/960558) [How to automatically merge .hgtags in Mercurial?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9783478/960558)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, ls-remote (used inside repo) with Git-URL show references into this URL from local, yes?

If you want to know for Mercurial, which remote repositories it know (*not used* for push|pull, only *know*), you can use `hg paths`

If you want for some random URL define, is it Mercurial repo or not, you can at least to try clone from this URL

Comment: git ls-remote can be used outside of a git repo. `git ls-remote $url` returns true if `$url` points to a valid git repo. I'm looking for something similar for mercurial, without having to create a clone.