# How to clone a repository for which i don't know the version control system used?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, repository, version

I have to check out a repository and its URL is like :

**ssh://user@server/path**

I have no other information that if the version-system is git or svn or something else.

Is there is a way to checkout that repository without this piece of information ?

I am using Ubuntu on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. It can be not repository (of any SCM), but just directory of files
2. Who give you this URL? Ask him about used VCS
3. If you have both Git and Mercurial and want to use "native" tools with repo, you can use trick from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145854/check-if-a-url-is-a-mercurial-repository-like-git-ls-remote)

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
git clone ssh://user@server/path
```

It's almost for sure a git repo.