# How to check for conflicts during interactive git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I often use `git rebase -i <ancestor>` to reorder commits during development to clean up my frequently small commits by grouping related commits together.  However my reordering has a tendency to lead to merge conflicts when a later hunk is reordered before an earlier hunk that overlaps.

Is there a way to assess whether conflicts will occur for a particular order before initiating the rebase?

Example:

```
$ git rebase -i 800adf8

# Interactive Rebase
pick 800adf8 initial commit
pick 2647ae9 content: add header       <--+
pick b0a2be6 content: add navbar          |   hunks overlap
pick 8b86f8a header: add stylesheet    <--+
pick 1da6209 content: add footer
pick 7d55152 header: add jquery
pick 515c410 content: add form
```

```
# After reorder
pick 800adf8 initial commit
pick 8b86f8a header: add stylesheet    <-- conflict
pick 7d55152 header: add jquery
pick 2647ae9 content: add header       <-- conflict
pick 1da6209 content: add footer
pick b0a2be6 content: add navbar
pick 515c410 content: add form
```

Note: I only rebase commits in my local repo that are not pushed to a public repo.  I am not looking for advice on best practices.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not :(

Comment: As knittl says there's nothing built in.  You could find out, though, by making your proposed reordering and then running a series of `git cherry-pick` operations (on a detached HEAD) to see if any of those result in a conflict.  If you get a conflict, there's your answer; if not, there's your result: move the branch label to the latest detached HEAD, and your rebase is complete.  (In other words, just do it, and see if there's a conflict.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, there was a [similar question for mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4086724/6309), and the conclusion was similar to [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123508/how-to-check-for-conflicts-during-interactive-git-rebase#comment39102687_25123508): you need to simulate the rebase and check if there is any conflict.

This [2010 article](http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/08/hopefully-useful-techniques-for-git.html) had a similar advice:

> Review the revision history of master, look for commits likely to contain significant conflicts or representing significant inflection points, and pick your next target commit around them;
>
> if you have a pile of simple commits, you might want the target to be the last such simple commit prior to a big one, for instance.
>   If you have a bunch of big hairy commits you may want each to be its own target/stage, etc.
>
> Use your knowledge of the app.